# How to get records with time close to Minutes = 59 And Second "close" to 59 from BD using EF

Tags: entity-framework, linq, datetime, linq-to-sql

Imagine the service that writes temperature samples from sensor into DB each 10 seconds. Now I need to display these temperature values in 24-hrs report displaying only values closest to 59th minute and 59th second, neglecting the rest records stored in DB.

I started with

```
var query = x.Discretes.AsQueryable();
query = query.Where(dcrts => dcrts.CreationTimestamp >= startTime && dcrts.CreationTimestamp <= endTime);
query = query.Where(hrsDiscretes => hrsDiscretes.CreationTimestamp.Minute == 59);
```

But don't know how to make EF select the single record with max Second value for each of these Hour's records in the query...